# Compile tcl file in linux

Tags: compilation, tcl

I wrote script in tcl and want to protect it.
Is there any way to compile the script so no one could see the code inside?

What is the conventional way to protect tcl script?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways, depending on the level of sophistication of protection you want:

1. Against the least sophisticated users, just changing the extensions on the filenames may be enough (e.g., `foobar.tcl` to `foobar.private`).
2. You can wrap the files up inside an archive of some sort (e.g., a [starkit](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Starkit), or a [ZIP archive](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/zipfs.htm) which is natively supported in Tcl 8.7); the archive might be combinable with a suitable runtime to make a single-file executable.
3. You can use the [Tcl Dev Kit](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Dev+Kit)'s “compiler” (Tcler's wiki page has many links) to create an obfuscated bytecode file. This requires a small extension to load, but the obfuscation is enough to defeat all but the most sophisticated of attackers. This can be mixed with the previous two techniques.
4. The ultimate in protecting a file is to use a full compiler like [tclquadcode](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tclquadcode) (experimental, but might do good things for you). The output of such programs is *exceptionally* hard to reverse engineer; it looks like machine code from another planet!
5. If even that's not enough, you have to go down the route of running the code as a [web service](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/application+server) and only allowing users to use it remotely; stealing code is (theoretically) impossible in that scenario, or at least (practically) incredibly difficult. This is a very large topic of its own.

Comment: Putting the TDK .tbc files in a password-protected ZIP-encoded single-file executable image — a combination of what you can do with options 2 and 3 — will result in code that will take even an experienced programmer several days to reverse engineer, unless they've got very special tools for the job (I don't know anyone who's made such public; there's a few non-standard steps that make this tricky). Method 4 is something you might do for other reasons, and 5 is a _different business model_ but hyper-resistant to people seeing the source code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to obfuscate your TCL file. Check [this](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Obfuscation).

Comment: This can be considered a 'link-only answer' and would not be useful if the link you used is not available anymore. You are encouraged to have your answer be self sufficient, so that it retains its usefulness without any external links.